# np.gradient - correct use?

Tags: python, numpy, derivative

I'm trying to use np.gradient to calculate a derivative, but I'm getting strange results and want to check that I'm using it correctly to eliminate that as a possible error.

A have a function y(x) over a range of equally spaced (but not unity) x-value data points.
I compute the derivative by

```
deriv = np.gradient(y, dx)
```

Is this correct application? Some very wild values creep into my results, which only worsen as I iterate this function in a model I'm developing.

Comment: can you provide piece of the sample data? and the wired result you get? Generally based on what you described, you are using it correctly.

Comment: the data is a 1D array with 2E5 values of an electrical current sampled at equally spaced distances (my x array).  The weird values are occasional large spikes (rogue points) in the result, which increase in number and magnitude in successive iterations of my model.

Comment: If you want to cluster your current signal, then you properly shouldn't not use this kind of simple algorithm to cluster. Or maybe you could smooth your signal before running the `gradient` fucntion?

Answer (score 1):

Looks right to me.  Derivative of sin is cos.  When I plot `np.gradient` of my sin function, it looks identical to when I plot cos directly.

An example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
pd.Series(y).plot()
```

[image]

```
y2 = np.gradient(y, 0.01)
pd.Series(y2).plot()
```

[image]

```
y3 = np.cos(x)
pd.Series(y3).plot()
```

[image]